Changing background color and text input color in next ui
import {Input} from "@nextui-org/react";

<Input            
   label="Email" 
   radius='sm' />


I want to be able to independently customize the input text color and the label color too. I have tried to style using tailwind but I have failed. Is there anyone who can assist me with this?

I'm unclear on what exactly you want to do. Do you want the color to be a Next UI theme color or a custom color. Can you add the tailwind css code you used?

i want to be able to input my own custom color on both the label and the input element

According to the documentation, you can use classNames to specify styles for individual slots. In practice, however, some styles may be conflicting, and you may need to raise the selector specificity to specify your style:
<Input
  classNames={{
    label: "!text-amber/500 dark:!text-amber-500/90",
    input: ["bg-transparent", "!text-blue-500/90 dark:!text-blue-500/90"],
  }}
  label="Email"
  radius="sm"
/>

